# Windows 2003 SQL Server 2005 maintenance and server load/usage

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm a developer who inherited a Win2k3 box in a small shop with a database server (SQL Server). What kinds of things do I need to know to monitor the server and see what processes cause the most problems/use the most system resources?

Is there a handy utility that will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Heartbeat from sqlsolutions.com will give you a realtime view of whats going on all the time (including the running query).  Its a free app but they also have a full solution to monitor everything (deadlocks/long running queries/etc.).  Using the Sql Hearbeat is probably a good start.  You'll want to start educating yourself about Sql Server to set up maintenance plans and backups to make sure you are covered.

Answer (score 0):

There's a large selection of dynamic management views (DMVs) in SQL Server itself, where you can read in Books Online how to use them.